# Double Records Added After Enabling Client Side Validation And Submitting form in Yii

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, validation, yii

I have a following simple form in Yii that is submitted by AJAX:

```
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id' => 'application-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
        'enableClientValidation' => true,
        'htmlOptions' => array(
            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
            'onsubmit'=>"return send();"
        ),
        'clientOptions'=>array('validateOnSubmit'=>true)

)); ?>
<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'name', array('size' => 60,'maxlength' => 255)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model, 'name'); ?>
    </div>
<div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>
```

And function for submitting:

```
function send (){

var data_form=$("#application-form").serialize();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('admin/application/create') ?>",
    dataType:'json',
    data: data_form,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
        alert("success",textStatus);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       // console.log( errorThrown);

    }
});
return false;
}
```

My create controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Application;
        $model->setScenario('create');

       $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if (isset($_POST['Application'])) {

           if ( $model->save()){

                echo CJSON::encode(array('success' => 'true','id'=>$model->id));
                Yii::app()->end();
            }
        }

        $this->render('create', array(
            'model' => $model
        ));
    }
```

Filed name is required and that is only validation for now. When I try to submit form without field name inputted, validation messages appear as they supposed to do in Yii. But when I fill form correctly, my model is inputted twice in database. If I remove following property:

```
'clientOptions'=>array('validateOnSubmit'=>true)
```

model gets saved correctly (only one time), but no validation messages appear.

How can I get default validation messages in Yii to appear, when I submit my form via ajax and model not to be saved twice. I need to submit form this way, because I will return model id in Ajax response for processing in JavaScript.

I searched the web for this and tried all suggestions, but none of them work.

Thank you all!

Comment: **Update**  I solved by adding `'afterValidate'=>'js:function(form,data,hasError){
       send(form,data,hasError);` and removing `'onsubmit'=>"return send();"` line. Now it shows validation errors and only saves model once. Check http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/11679-aftervalidate-beforevalidate-setting-in-php/ this post for more info.

Comment: please, consider to post your comment as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by adding `'afterValidate'=>'js:function(form,data,hasError){ send(form,data,hasError);` and removing `'onsubmit'=>"return send();"` line. Now it shows validation errors and only saves model once.

Check [this post](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/11679-aftervalidate-beforevalidate-setting-in-php/) for more info.